# Vim question in Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, questions

May I ask a Vim question on Stack Overflow, while **Vi and Vim** Community is in beta and has low activity?

[This is the question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/4733/undo-diffget-in-vimdiff) that is currently in **Vi and Vim**, that I would like to move to Stack Overflow.

Comment: No, I don't think that would be a good fit for SO; it's not really a programming problem, *per se*, more how to use the tool.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Well there are currently approx. [17500 questions tagged vim](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/vim). Don't you think that it fits under "software tools commonly used by programmers"?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes, you are right, that's the major argument against posting it in SO.

Comment: @user000001 so do you think it would be ok to post in SO? And if majority will consider it off-topic, it will be closed anyway.

Comment: Why vim needs its own SE site is one of the great mysteries of life.  You'll have to give them a chance to answer it, 9 minutes isn't nearly enough on a site with such low traffic.  And give them a break, those screenshots are completely unreadable.  Something you can work on while you wait for an answer.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks, how would you improve those? Add annotations or convert to ascii-art, etc?

Answer (score 6):

It is absurd to not allow questions about a programming tool on SO, even more so for a *text editor*, the most fundamental programming tool of all. SO already allows for plenty of questions about IDEs and other text editors (such as Sublime Text), not to mention source control tools (like SourceTree).

If it weren't for the fact that [Vi and Vim beta](https://vi.stackexchange.com/) exists, I would say go ahead and post on Stack Overflow. If you end up getting no response on the beta site for a while, consider re-posting the question to SO.